# Proving a triangle to be isosceles.

Tags: triangles, circles, conic-sections, tangent-line

> From a point $(P)$ on auxiliary circle of an ellipse a perpendicular is dropped on major axis of ellipse. The perpendicular cuts ellipse at another point $(Q)$.
>   Now from one of the focus $(S)$ of ellipse a perpendicular is dropped on tangent at point $(R)$ on point $(P)$.
>   Prove that $\triangle QRS$ is isosceles.
>   [image]

Finding coordinates of points $Q,R,S$ is a lengthy process.
I need a different method to deal with this question.
Thanks in advance for any hints of solution.

Comment: Please provide a picture. Since the text cannot be easily digested (at least from my point of view), please introduce  objects one by one, step for step. First introduce the ellipse, than the auxiliary circle, than the point on it. (This is a good style for my taste.) Using the same strategy of the order of things, please define first $R$, than which tangent to what is taken, than which perpendicular, and so on. Please insure that the statement is clear, not a language puzzle itself, so that we can concentrate on the geometry. Own real tries are then still welcome...

Comment: @dan_fulea-It is quite easy to understand and the question was quoted the same way. Thats why I posted it without a picture. I will try to make picture and attach it.

Comment: @dan_fulea-edited

Comment: Thanks fo the picture, 1+ now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us make a simple parametrization, so that the coordinates of the point $R$ are visible by simple means:

[image: Problem 2902800]

In the picture, $O$ is the intersection of the axes of the ellipse, then $OP\|SR$ being both perpendicular on the tangent in $P$ to the external (major) auxiliary circle of the ellipse. We choose $T$ such that $PRST$ is a rectangle. Then we can easily characterize the vector $\overset \to{PR}=\overset \to{TS}$ from the data in the triangle $\Delta TOS$ with hypotenuse $OS=c=\sqrt{a^ 2-b^2}$ by using the angle $\angle TOS=\angle POS$ as a parameter. Let $TU$ be its height. Then we list:
$$
\begin{aligned}
TO &= OS\cos t=c\cos t\ ,\\
TU &= TO\sin t=c\sin t\cos t\ ,\\
US &= TS\cos(90^\circ-t)=OS\sin t\cos(90^\circ-t)=c\sin^2 t\ ,\\
P &= (a\cos t,a\sin t)\ ,\\
Q &= (a\cos t,b\sin t)\ ,\\
R &= P+(US,-TU)=a(\cos t,\sin t)+c\sin t(\sin t,-\cos t)\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{(which can be written directly from the picture)}\\
S &= (c,0)\ ,\\
SR
&=\|\ (a\cos t-c\cos^2 t, a\sin t-c\sin t\cos t)\ \|\\
&=(a-c\cos t)\;\|\ (\cos t, \sin t)\ \|\\
&=a-c\cos t\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{(or simpler $SR=TP=OP-OT=a-c\cos t$)}\\
SQ^2 
&=\|\ (c-a\cos t,-b\sin t)\ \|^2\\
&= c^2-2ac\cos t + a^2\cos^2 t+b^2 \sin^2 t\\
&= c^2\cos^2 t-2ac\cos t + a^2\cos^2 t+ c^2\sin^2 t +b^2 \sin^2 t \\
&= c^2\cos^2 t-2ac\cos t + a^2\\
&= (a-c\cos t)^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

So $SQ=SR$.

$\square$

(The path to the solution can be simplified, some of the relations omitted, but i usually give "them" all. For instance, we do not need analytically the coordinates of $R$, it is enough to compute $SR=TP=OP-OT$...)